# HighCharts Legend placement

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighCharts (horizontal) bar chart. This chart is very long down my page, which is fine, and so I was hoping to have the legend show up at the top and bottom of the chart. Is this possible? I cannot find in the API how to do this.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: here is jsfiddle example of what i am doing. notice that the legend is at the top but since the chart is vertically long i was hoping to have legend at top and bottom of page. 

http://jsfiddle.net/tarpatel/ND9fT/1/

Answer (score 4):

You can add extra legend by CSS / html styles.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ecrww/109/

```
 $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
    $('<li style="color: '+serie.color+'">'+serie.name+'</li>').click(function(){
        serie.visible ? serie.hide() : serie.show();
    }).appendTo('#legend')
})
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, not quite what I was expecting. I was hoping to get a high charts solution. I am surprised that there is no option in high charts to have multiple legends. 

But I am very glad you replied because you have opened my eyes to new functionality that I was not aware available to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the following code

```
legend:
 {
  layout: 'vertical',
  align: 'right',
  verticalAlign: 'top'
  ......
  ......
 }
```

which makes the legend to default position

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I would like to see the legend at top and bottom of chart. please see my comment to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I also got it and found this way to solve it

try adding these code in options:

```
    chart: {
            marginTop:-10//for top position
           },
```

hope it helps you